# Pythonic way to quickly parse XML stream to list of dicts

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I'm stuck at parsing XML to list of dicts to Pandas-like dataframe.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
"""
It's very important for parsing!
"""
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from table import Table

def xml_to_pd(xml):
    tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
    xmltag = tree.tag
    doc_dict = {}
    res = []

    for doc in tree.iter():
        if doc.attrib:
            if doc_dict not in res and len(doc_dict)>0:
                res.append(doc_dict)
                doc_dict = {}
                doc_dict = (doc.attrib)

            if doc.text:
                key = doc.tag
                value = doc.text
                doc_dict[key] = (value)

        else:
            if doc.text:
                key = doc.tag
                value = doc.text
                doc_dict[key] = (value)

            else:
                if doc_dict != {}:
                    if doc_dict not in res:
                        res.append(doc_dict)
                doc_dict = {}

    if doc_dict != {}:
        if doc_dict not in res:
            res.append(doc_dict)
            doc_dict = {}
    df = pd.DataFrame(res)
    return df

table = pd.DataFrame()

allxml = ['<markets><market id="1">MMVB</market><market id="4">FORTS</market><market id="15">ETS</market></markets>',
'<sec_info_upd><secid>1538</secid><seccode>SV16BL5</seccode><market>4</market><bgo_c>11908.97</bgo_c><bgo_nc>10307.27</bgo_nc><bgo_buy>4789.49</bgo_buy></sec_info_upd>',
'<quotes><quote secid="3630"><board>FUT</board><seccode>SiZ5</seccode><price>68079</price><buy>-1</buy></quote><quote secid="3630"><board>FUT</board><seccode>SiZ5</seccode><price>68132</price><buy>2</buy></quote></quotes>']

for xml in allxml:
    res = xml_to_pd(xml)
    for r in res:
        table = pd.concat([table, res])
    print '\n\r'
    print table
```

The idea was to build a table from each XML expression, but I'm getting strange mixed-in results and also **not quite sure if I'm doing it right way**.

Please don't care about Pandas, actually I'll be using another, lightweight storage table object accepting list of dicts just like pandas DataFrame does.

Also it's very time-critical, because xml feed is provided from stock market every ~10 millisecons. So, the question is: how should I do this right and fast?

Really need your help, because I'm completely stuck in this xml hell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use setdefaultencoding... [See here for details](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).

Comment: That's the easiest way to avoid all the pain and just to concentrate on a main goal: the code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my (ugly) solution:

```
def xml_to_pd(self, xml):
    tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
    self.xmltag = tree.tag
    doc_dict = {}
    res = []
    for doc in tree.iter():
        if doc.tag in doc_dict.keys():
            res.append (doc_dict)
            doc_dict = {}
        if doc.attrib:
            if doc_dict!= {} and doc_dict not in res:
                for k in doc.attrib.keys():
                    if k in doc_dict:
                        res.append (doc_dict)
                        doc_dict = {}

                doc_dict.update (doc.attrib)
            else:
                doc_dict.update(doc.attrib)
        if doc.text:
                key = doc.tag
                value = doc.text
                doc_dict[key] = value
    if doc_dict not in res and doc_dict != {}:
        res.append (doc_dict)
        doc_dict = {}
    return res

Table() is my custom 'dataframe' class.
```

**UPDATED A YEAR LATER.**

```
def xml_to_dict(self, xmltext):
    doc = xmltodict.parse(xmltext)
    _res = {}

    for key, value in doc.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            stripped_dict = {}
            for subkey in value.keys():
                stripped_key = subkey.strip('@')
                stripped_dict[stripped_key] = value[subkey]
            _res.update(stripped_dict)
        else:
            _res[key] = value
    return _res
```